# How to set/add key value pairs in a map when value should be a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, merge, immutable.js

I am mapping through a key value pairs which are :

```
a => a1
a => a2 
a => a3

b => b1
b => b2 
b => b3

c => c1
c => c2 
c => c3
```

now I have a map:

```
const myobject = new Map()
```

I need to set the data above in my map in a way that every key has a value which is a list like:

```
a => list[a1, a2, a3] 
b => list[b1, b2, b3] 
c => list[c1, c2, c3]
```

here is the actual code:

```
const serviceResponses = new Map();
await Promise.all(allPromise.map(promises => {
   promises.then(promise => promise.map(([stateName, item]) => {
            // below is the part I am trying to set stateName (string)  and 
            // result (it should be an array) into serviceResponses which is a 
            // map. note: result always has the same number of items. in this 
            // example the number of items is 3, but it can be any number. 
            item[0].then(result => {
                        serviceResponses.set(stateName, result);
                });
                return serviceResponses;
           }));
```

I went through Immutablr.js api docs and I already tried, setIn, set, MergeIn, MergeDeep.
Thanks for the help

Comment: are these two maps? Could you clarify. I don't know what *mapping through a key value pairs* means.I appreciate the effort to visually display, but sometimes it's best to just show what the actual code is. We need to know where you're getting your initial data from and what type of variable it's stored in.

Comment: @zfrisch I added more information in the question.

Comment: I still do not get what the problem is? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I mean, apart from the fact that setting `serviceResponse` creates a new map, which is thrown away and that `withMutations` should be used for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)

If you're purely wondering how to set the values, just do:

```
myobject.set('a', [a1, a2, a3]);
```

Comment: I do not know the number of items in the array it can be any number